# want to use group by clause and sum aggregator together

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    state_name AS State_Names,
    totaloccupancy AS Total_OccupiedProperties,
    totalproperty AS Total_Properties, 
    CAST(ROUND(totaloccupancy * 100.0 / totalproperty, 1) AS REAL) AS Occupancy_Percentage 
FROM 
    OCCUPANCYPERCENTAGE
```

Output:

```
State_Names Total_OccupiedProperties    Total_Properties    Occupancy_Percentage
Florida 2   2   100
Florida 1   2   50
Florida 13  16  81.3
Florida 40  51  78.4
Georgia 2   2   100
Georgia 49  54  90.7
Georgia 4   4   100
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 17  17  100
Georgia 7   7   100
Georgia 6   7   85.7
Georgia 15  19  78.9
Georgia 8   9   88.9
Georgia 33  34  97.1
Georgia 9   9   100
Georgia 2   2   100
Georgia 14  18  77.8
Georgia 2   2   100
Georgia 10  12  83.3
Georgia 1   2   50
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 9   10  90
Georgia 1   3   33.3
Georgia 2   2   100
Georgia 32  36  88.9
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 6   6   100
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 87  99  87.9
Georgia 4   6   66.7
Georgia 2   3   66.7
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 9   12  75
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 4   4   100
Georgia 6   6   100
Georgia 2   3   66.7
Georgia 7   7   100
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 2   2   100
Georgia 6   7   85.7
Georgia 46  54  85.2
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 1   1   100
Georgia 1   2   50
Georgia 5   6   83.3
Georgia 68  84  81
Georgia 2   2   100
Georgia 3   3   100
Georgia 15  18  83.3
Georgia 7   7   100
Georgia 1   1   100
```

Now I want to group by state to get total occupied property, total property, and total occupancy percentage, but I get an error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
> Column 'OCCUPENCYPERCENTAGE.totaloccupancy' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Kindly help

Comment: Can you please post your SQL statement that you tried to group by

Comment: **Typo** alert - it's **occupancy** - not "occupency" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CAST(ROUND(totaloccupancy * 100.0 / totalproperty, 1) AS FLOAT) AS Occupancy_Percentage
```

try to CAST as FLOAT